# Field level access rights and Security in openerp 7

Tags: python, security, csv, odoo, access-rights

Suppose I have 3 users which are as follows:

```
user_employee having access rights Human Resource /Employee group
user_officer having access rights Human Resource /officer group
user_manager having access rights Human Resource /manager group
```

For object `hr_employee(hr.employee)`

If I am logged in as `user_manager` or `user_officer` I can create/edit my own employee record.  If I am logged in as `user_employee` I cannot edit my own employee record.

Then I gave write permission to Human Resource/Employee group and now I can edit all fields which are related to `hr_employee`, but I want to restrict edit access to users which are under Human Resource/Employee group to certain fields; for example if `user_employee` is logged in then he is not able to edit `department_id` or `related_user`, or `coach_id`, `active`, `manager`, etc.

He can edit just his name, address, DOB, and other public information.

How can I solve this issue with security folder files like `.xml` or `.csv` files?

Comment: Help get the OpenERP site going!  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43481/openerp?referrer=CbZ7bL3fh2QdmpKS2kqovw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.xml` and `.csv` files provide security settings on a broader scale: `create`, `read`, `update`, and `delete`.

If you want per field settings instead you'll have to play around with the xml view file.  Check out the `domain` settings.

Something like:

```
<field name="DOB" attrs="{'readonly':[('groups_id.category_id.name','=','Human Resource')]}"/>
```

The above is not restrictive enough, but hopefully will give you the idea.

As convenient as this might be, I don't think it's a good idea.  Depending on the laws of where your company is located, the company can be responsible for the accuracy of that data.  Having the employee present evidence of any changes to somebody in HR can be a good thing.

Comment: Hi I am trying to make a group invisible but it's throwing an error is this not possible attrs="{'invisible':[('groups_id.category_id.name','=','Human Resource')]}" ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DanMendes: Please open a new question and include the version of OpenERP you are using, the module you using/creating, and any errors messages.