# Kanban View Readonly For Group In a Specific Kanban Stage

Tags: odoo, kanban

I'm developing a kanban View in OpenERP 7 for a restaurant module,
The view is to display the food status ordered by customers.
currently the stage is:

> - Waiting Queue
> - In Progress
> - Ready to be served
> - Is Served
> - Cancelled

I've created 2 groups :

> - Waiters
> - Chef

When the user's group is waiters , he/she can only modify  the record if the stage is 'Ready to be Served'.
For Chef, he/she can only modify a record if the stage is 'Waiting Queue' or 'In Progress'.

How do I set a domain / Access Rights for this kind of situation ?
This is my Kanban View's XML:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inno_master_kitchen_kanban_view">
        <field name="name">Master Kitchen</field>
        <field name="model">inno.master.kitchen</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <kanban default_group_by="state" create="false">
                <field name="state"/>
                <field name="customer_id"/>
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <field name="product_qty"/>
                <field name="table_name"/>
                <field name="order_reference"/>
                <templates>
                    <t t-name="kanban-box">
                      <div class="kitchen_kanban oe_kanban_color_0 oe_kanban_card">
                          <div class="oe_kanban_box_header ">
                                <b><field name="table_name"/></b>
                          </div>
                          <div class="oe_kanban_content">
                              <img style="float:left;" t-att-src="kanban_image('product.product', 'image_medium', record.product_id.raw_value)" class="oe_kanban_image" />
                              <div><b><field name="order_reference"/></b></div>
                              <div><field name="product_id"/></div>
                              <div>
                                <field name="product_qty"/>
                                <field name="product_uom"/>
                              </div>
                              <img style="float:right;" t-att-src="kanban_image('res.partner', 'image_small', record.customer_id.raw_value)" width="24" height="24" t-att-title="record.customer_id.value" class="oe_kanban_avatar" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="oe_clear"></div>
                      </div>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: May this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672455/field-level-access-rights-and-security-in-openerp-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply give right permission to update state field.

Or

over ride write method & do proper code & raise message that you can't do this.

> ```
> def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
>     res = super(crm_lead, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context)
>     warning = {}
>     if vals.get('stage_id'):
>         stage = self.pool.get('crm.case.stage').browse(cr, uid, vals['stage_id'], context=context)
>         if stage.name == 'Pre Sale':
>             #raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('You cannot confirm a sales order which has no line.'))
>             dummy,group_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, 1, 'base', 'group_sale_manager')
>             user_groups = self.pool.get('res.users').read(cr, uid, [uid], context)[0]['groups_id']
>             if group_id not in user_groups:
>                 raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('You are not a sales manager and so you are not allowed to win this thing'))
>     return res
> ```

Comment: it works ! I've never expected that write is executed in kanban view's change state ,
thanks tejas!

Comment: @Edxz: Read more articles at snippetbucket.com/news, I am sure it helps you a lot.