# OpenERP attrs invisible is not working

Tags: odoo

I am trying to make a group invisible in view if the user does not belong to human resources... this is part of multiple conditions to filter groups, this is the most basic one, this is on form view:

```
attrs="{'invisible':[('groups_id.category_id.name','=','Human Resource')]}"
```

However that trows an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown field groups_id.category_id.name
```

If i use

```
attrs="{'readonly':[('groups_id.category_id.name','=','Human Resource')]}"
```

that error does not occur but it does not appear to do anything...

even `attrs="{'readonly':[('1','=','1')]}"` does not appear to do anything.

If i add `<group invisible="1"`

it works as expected.

Why doesn't invisible work? Also if i type anything in attrs other than invisible it appears to parse the XML without issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is attrs are evaluated by the client which means there isn't a browse record and the client can't resolve the groups_id.category_id... 
Attrs can only work on fields available to the client so extend the model and add a related field. Put this on the view with invisible = 1 so the user doesn't see it and use this field on your attrs.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean... attrs is on the XML so it should be parsed server side, right? I am not exaclty sure what the workaround you describe looks like, but all the logic is tied up by the user belonging to a certain group, certain fields should only be visible if he belongs to a certain group, but for his own record he has access to all fields.

Comment: The XML is stored on the server side yes, and is parsed when you update the module but the attrs is evaluated by the client and is in the general OpenERP form of a list of tuples (field, operator, value), e.g. ('my_field', '=', 'a') or ('my_boolean_field', '=', True).  You need to write some python code to either change or extend the model you are displaying to add a field that resolves the groups_id.category_id.name and then put this onto the view as a field and then your attrs domain would be ('my_new_field', '=', 'Human Resource').

Comment: OK. Thanks for your reply Adrien. It appears that I need to write some python code to achieve this, the goal of this project was to write if possible no code and use as much as possible the default way of OpenERP with configurations. If I add a field with the name of the department to my model, I will try to sell that solution to my PM.

Comment: Hmm, if you really don't want to write some code... (1) Create a new group through the menu and put your users in it then (2) from Settings -> User Interface -> Views - find the view you want and edit the XML so it says groups="my_new_group".  Gotcha is when you next update the module, the XML won't change unless you manually delete the view record first.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in `attrs` you can only pass OpenERP basic `"domain"`.

The domain is parsed by the Web client. That force you to have all fields used in domain in the view event if not shown, they must be invisible fields.

The domain value must be static.

```
attrs = "{'readonly': [('my_filed_must_be_in_view', '=', 'static_value')]}"
```

You can not use complex function, or server related code the scope is limited to the view.

Comment: I got the idea from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672455/field-level-access-rights-and-security-in-openerp-7 so this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WE can not use object fields relation here to fetch value inside ATTRS Though we can use this kind of feature with DOMAIN!